# Webbrowser Control, Screen Resolution and scrollbars

Tags: scrollbar, webbrowser-control

I have an Click Once application that utilizes a webbrowser control inside of a tab control that functions like a tabbed browser.  When it is used at 1280x960 and lower resolutions the bottom scrollbar disappears and the right side of the web page is cut off.  Looking for any ideas on what may be causing it and/or how to resolve it.

I add add the webbrower control using code:

```
TabControl.TabPages.Add("New Page")
WebBrowser1 = New WebBrowser
WebBrowser1.Name = "Browse Web"
WebBrowser1.Doc = DockStyle.Fill
TabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(WebBrowser1)

CType(TabControl.SelectedTablControls.Item(0), WebBrowser).GoHome()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be unrelated to the code.  The main form had a width of 1500 and when it displayed on the 1280 resolution the webbrowser control apparently went to that width.  Changing the main form width to 1200 resolved the issue.